# Angular 9: interceptor cyclic dependency while injecting lazy loaded service

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular9

I face `Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` error while injecting my lazy loaded service in the interceptor.

However, so strange my problem is being solved by adding an empty `setTimeout(()` to the service injection in the interceptor. I am wondering why that happens though...

the lazy loaded **LanguageService**:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()

export class LanguageService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private _translate: TranslateService) {
    this.getLanguages();
  }
// ....
```

the **interceptor**:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LanguageService } from '../app/blog/services/language.service';

@Injectable()

export class LanguageInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private _languageService:LanguageService;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        /*  This way Works!
            setTimeout(() => {
            this._languageService = this.injector.get(LanguageService)
         })*/

      
            this._languageService = this.injector.get(LanguageService)
         
    }
    
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
```

the **interceptor barrel**:

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LanguageInterceptor } from './lang-interceptor';

export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LanguageInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

the **shared module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { httpInterceptorProviders } from 'src/utilities/interceptor-barrel';
import { ShareModule } from '@ngx-share/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

const MODULES = [
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientJsonpModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    ShareModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MODULES,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            defaultLanguage: 'en',
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
    ],
    exports: [
        MODULES,
        TranslateModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [
        httpInterceptorProviders
    ],
})
```

the **lazy loaded module**:

```
 // ....
imports: [
        SharedModule
    ]
 // ....
 providers: [
        LanguageService
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `LanguageService` should not be added to the providers of the lazy loaded module. It should not be added to any `providers` array of a module. It should have a `providedIn: 'root'` in the decorator:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LanguageService {}

//  lazy loaded module
imports: [
  SharedModule
]

// ....
providers: []
```

Interceptors on the other hand, should either be declared in your core module, which is included in the App root once. Or in a lazy loaded module, to define a interceptor just for that lazy loaded module

---

You should restructure your application. Split up your `SharedModule` to -only- (!important) include components/pipes/directives. These are things that should go in a `SharedModule`. What -definitely- should not go in there, are application related services and imports.

By the looks of it, your `SharedModule` should be a `CoreModule`, and only be imported (not exported) in your `AppModule`. You should -not- import this module in a lazy loaded module. In your case it will redeclare the `HttpClientModule` -without- the interceptors, because they are declared in the root and not in the lazy module, making you have the issues you're facing.

Angular itself has a [good overview](https://angular.io/guide/module-types) of what kind of modules there are, and what they should and should not contain, and where they should be or should not be imported:

> There are five general categories of feature modules which tend to fall into the following groups:
>
> - Domain feature modules.
> - Routed feature modules.
> - Routing modules.
> - Service feature modules.
> - Widget feature modules.

Comment: I tried this but I don't know why the interceptor does not hit any of http requests when included in the app root module...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in where you include your interceptors. Your Interceptors should be part of your app/core module.

Comment: Thank you but this way the interceptor does not hit any of http requests

Comment: you have included it in providers of core module? it will work for sure. can you provide a stacblitz with minimal code?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, but I've finally found that I should restart the angular app and everything worked fine after the restart.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, but I feel that by restarting the app we're just hiding the issue under the carpet. There is something deeper going on here.

Comment: In my case, I have imported a new module and sometimes, angular doesn't feel the newly imported module tell it restarted.

Answer (score 0):

That error occur when you have to import your module inside imports but forgot to add in export section. **e.g:**

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
      ],
      imports: [
        RadioGroupModule,
      ],
      exports: [
        
      ],
    
    })
    export class SharedModule { }
```